# Oracle SQL BETWEEN not returning last value

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and after executing this command only names starting with `K` and `L` show up. Why names starting with `M` do not appear?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(names) FROM STUDENTS WHERE names BETWEEN 'K%' AND 'M%' ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

And when I execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(names) FROM STUDENTS WHERE names BETWEEN 'K%' AND 'N%' ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

`K`,`L`,`M` appear but names starting with `N` don't. `BETWEEN` is inclusive so what's the problem?

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE year BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

Answer (score 5):

The between predicate does not imply `like` so you're simply comparing strings. Write this instead

```sql
-- Names with starting letters K, L, M, N
names >= 'K' AND names < 'O'
```

Alternatively, use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adfns/regexp.html#GUID-1935FD80-A3CD-413F-BD2E-BBEFE64000B2)

```sql
-- Names with starting letters K, L, M
REGEXP_LIKE (names, '^[K-M]')
```

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: I answered the question *"K,L,M appear but names starting with N don't. BETWEEN is inclusive so what's the problem?"*

Comment: Sorry, now I re-read the explaining comments and got it!

Answer (score 1):

> BETWEEN is inclusive so what's the problem?

The wildcard '%' does not work as with `LIKE` here and [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) applies

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Mango' BETWEEN 'K%' AND 'M%' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS result
FROM dual
-- false

SELECT CASE WHEN 'Mango' >= 'K%' AND 'Mango' <= 'M%' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 
       AS result
FROM dual
--false

SELECT CASE WHEN 'Mango' >= 'K%' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS result
FROM dual
-- true

SELECT CASE WHEN 'Mango' <= 'M%' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS result
FROM dual
-- false
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbdd719a77b8d4c450759d52de2b3316)**

---

> This works perfectly:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE year BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
> ```

Rewriting in similar manner(though it is not SARGable):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(names) 
FROM STUDENTS 
WHERE SUBSTR(names,1,1) BETWEEN 'K' AND 'M' 
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lukas explained the problem -- confusing `LIKE` patterns with strings.  One other solution is:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(names, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'K' AND 'M'
```

Note that of the solutions mentioned, only the direct comparison:

```
WHERE names >= 'K' AND names < 'O'
```

will use an index.  However, with such a broad range of values, an index may not be useful for the query anyway.

Comment: If there is an index on `names`, it **will** definitely be used, regardless of selectivity and also regardless of which predicate is used. Since the query **only** selects names, everything will be read directly from the index; the table will not be accessed because it doesn't have to be. What may be different is **how** the predicate is used - full index scan vs. index range scan.

Comment: Did you test the index access @mathguy? Basically you are claiming Oracle *can* use index access (here `index_ffs`) even if there is a *function on the indexed column name* (here `SUBSTR(names,1,1)` ). I know that *in theory* this could be possible for `index_ffs` but my tests on 19c show *full table scan*.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - I said nothing about *access* (which means: scan the index first, apply some filters, then **access** rows from the base table). I said index **scan** - read all the data from the index; the base table doesn't need to be accessed AT ALL. With a function like SUBSTR, Oracle needs to know the column (`names`) is NOT NULL; I assume that would be true in a table like `students`. Also, I assume there is additional data (more columns) in the table; otherwise there's no benefit to reading the data from the index (small) vs. the full table (big).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - With these additional assumptions, I just tested, and indeed, the query will be execute via "index fast full scan". I am on Oracle 12.2, but I assume you will find the same in Oracle 19 if you set up the test correctly (as explained above).